# Connect to Flask application via public IP

Tags: python, windows, flask, centos, hosting

I currently have 2 computers, one with CentOS 7.x and one with Windows 10. Both have public IP-addresses.
**When I run my application on my Windows machine, I can access my website from the CentOS computer but not vice versa.**

I have turned off the firewalls temporary and it seems like it is not the problem. 
I want to host it on my CentOS computer.
In my windows application I have:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port = 8080, host = 'publicIPofWindows')
```

In CentOS i have:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port = 8080, host = 'publicIPofCentOS')
```

If I host on my CentOS machine I can access it from the CentOS computer.
Can someone please tell me what the problem might be? 
Do I have to install anything on my CentOS that is required for sharing? 
I know that I installed a lot of (probably most unnecessary) things on my Windows computer.

Comment: Set host to `'0.0.0.0'` and see if that does something?

Comment: I have already tried to set IP as 0.0.0.0, it doesn't change anything.